# SharePoint 2007: Determine who deleted a group

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Someone deleted a user group from my site. Does SharePoint keep any sort of log that will tell me who did it or when?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Site Collection Audit Logging enabled (Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Configure audit log settings,) which hopefully you do, you can view the Audit reports for the site. It will show the group deletion under "Security Settings"

Comment: I don't see that option. Is that only in the paid version?

Comment: @Jonathan: Just to avoid confusion: The "paid version" is SharePoint 2007. The Free Version is Windows SharePoint Services 3.0, or WSS3 for short. But WSS also includes Audit Logging: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc824909.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to check the IIS logs (configured in Central Admin -> Operations -> Usage Analysis Processing, will also tell you where they are stored if enabled).